# Program hangs and won't finish

Tags: java, while-loop, freeze

I'm writing a program that is supposed to take as input, several arrays of objects, and process them with the output being all the elements that the lists have in common.  In other words, find the intersection of three arrays.

When I attempt to run the program, it all goes fine until the program starts executing the while loop within findCommonElements().  It hangs there and doesn't step forward, and I can't figure out why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*edit* When the arrays are passed to this method, they are already sorted

```
public static Comparable[] findCommonElements(Comparable[][] collections) 
{
    team[] intersection = new team[50];

    int index = 0;
    int i = 0; //counter for collections[0]
    int j = 0; //counter for collections[1]
    int k = 0; //counter for collections[2]

    System.out.print("test");

    while (i < collections[0].length && j < collections[1].length && k < collections[2].length)
    {
        //if query value > collections[2] value, increment collections[2]
        if (collections[0][i].compareTo(collections[1][j]) > 0)
        {
            j++;
            incComparisons();

        }
        //if query value > collections[2] value, increment collections[2]
        else if (collections[0][i].compareTo(collections[2][k]) > 0)
        {
            k++;
            incComparisons();

        }
        else if (collections[0][i] == collections[1][j] && collections[0][i] == collections[2][k])
        {
            // add entry to intersection array
            intersection[index] = (team) collections[0][i];
            index++;
            incComparisons();


            // if the next item in each collection also matches, then add an extra instance of that item to the list
            if (collections[1][j + 1] == collections[0][i] || collections[2][k + 1] == collections[0][i])
            {
                intersection[index] = (team) collections[0][i];
                index++;
                incComparisons();

            }
            i++;
            j++;
            k++;
        }           
    }

    return intersection;
}
```

Comment: You want to add a tag telling the language you are using.

Comment: Did you try debugging step-by-step?

Comment: If all of your `if` statements evaluate to false, then `i,j and k` will not change, and the while loop will not complete.

Comment: I'm in the process of debugging it right now line by line.  Thanks for the tip, I'm new to Eclipse and java in general so I'm still kinda figuring things out.

In doing that I've found that indeed all my statements evaluate to false and the loop just keeps running over and over and over. At least this gives me a place to start.  Thanks again guys and gals!

Comment: Is it your intention to check for instance equality _==_ instead of Object equality _a.equals(b)_ ? Maybe this is why _i, j and k_ do not increase and your loop does not end..

Comment: That's one change I made.  I'm now using the compareTo() method in the team class to test for equality